# Drupal 7 - can't uninstall Features module

Tags: 7, features

i just started to mess up with Drupal 7 (and Drupal in general sense) - and i can't uninstall module named Features it gives error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: menu_custom: DELETE FROM {menu_custom} WHERE (menu_name = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => features ) in features_uninstall() (line 29 of /Users/umren/projects/LAMP/sites/all/modules/features/features.install).
```

p.s. i'm using sqlite if it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `menu_custom` table which is defined by the menu module. Most likely the problem is dependencies. If you install the menu module, that should fix it. If the menu module is already installed, the problem is that your database is broken.

Comment: menu was disabled, i was in minimal setup.. that did it!